# How to check for repeating records e.g username when entering records into database

Tags: php

I am trying to ensure that a username cant be repeated when entering records to a database..I am getting this error "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Syokimaufc\register.php "  My user id field has been auto increemented and that seems to be the issue. how do i fix this?

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $tel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tel']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);

     $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membership WHERE Username = '".$username."'");

     if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
     {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, that username is taken. Please go back and try again.</p>";
     }
     else
     {
        $registerquery
 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO membership (username, password, email, tel, address) 
VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."','".$tel."','".$address."')");
        if($registerquery)
        {
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
            echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
        }       
     }
}
else
{
    ?>
```

Comment: check your query success/not . before execute `mysql_num_rows()` also don use `empty()` use `isset()`. finally use `mysqi`

Comment: Try [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate user names simply create [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) on the user name column in your database. Then, if you try to insert duplicate user name, the insert query will fail and you can react on the failure. No need to lookup user name in the database before inserting the new one.

And don't use `mysql_*` functions, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. And set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, so you get a nice exception when duplicate user name is detected.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. I mean db constraint is a good thing, but only as a safe guard - not for flow controll. First: You will need to parse exceptions if you want to tell user what happened (was it duplicated username or e-mail, or sth else). Second: Logic depends on storage engine and you shouldn't expect it there. Its either prone to bugs or brings overcomplicated tests. Registration is rare operation and its overall cost is low (even hash generation is purposefully slowed down) - there won't be any harm in additional query.

Answer (score 0):

In your select query Username should be username. So your query should be SELECT * FROM membership WHERE username = '".$username."'". You should use mysqli instead since mysql functions are no longer supported